# Google Sheets formula to remove all punctuation excluding period (.)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Would appreciate some help with a Google Sheets formula to remove all punctuation excluding period (.)

I'm currently using the formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D2,"[[:punct:]]", " ")
```

However this removes all punctuation and I need the periods to remain.

| Input | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| cpe:2.3:a:caldera:openlinux_server:3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:* | cpe 2.3 a caldera openlinux server 3.1 |
| cpe:2.3:o:trustix:secure_linux:1.01:*:*:*:*:*:*:* | cpe 2.3 o trustix secure linux 1.01 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2, "[:,_\*]", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry mate that doesn't look to have had the output expected. It doesn't remove any of the punctuation.